# Sidebar menu does not work when using "include" for the HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help to figure out this one:

When I have the HTML-code for the menu written separately in each document, the sidebar menu works perfectly, but when I use the following javascript to include the menu, it won't show the HTML-code in the menu:

```
<div w3-include-html="menu.html"></div> 
<script>
   w3IncludeHTML();
</script>
```

Any suggestions why this happens?

I hope you can help me!

Comment: can you also post what is inside this function?

Comment: Ehm it's a function from W3.JS and it works with some other HTML code I include through the function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have properly linked W3.JS, this should work when you just fix small typo. Instead of `w3IncludeHTML();` you should have `w3.IncludeHTML();`

```
<script>
   w3.includeHTML();
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I've linked to W3.JS, and it actually works fine with the footer, but It does not work with the sidebar menu..